# iOS Chats list control

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am looking for a Chats List control for iOS, as shown on the pic, if there is one in the world:
[image]

There are many controls and code examples on how to implement the actual messages view (that renders message bubbles), but I wasn't able to find any for displaying the list of the dialogs (with "unread messages count" badges, last message, avatar images, date of last message, name of the conversation partner). Any pointers to relevant/buildable Obj-c/Swift code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That just looks like a tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own Chat list using `UITableView` Inside that take `UITableViewCell`
and in cell, take `UIImageView` and `UILabel` for Username, Last message, Badge, Message time.

Now update your badge, messages, time etc when you receive push notification. What you need for chat list will not available ready made all the time, rather you should create by your own customisation and use when needed.

Let me know if you need anything else.